# how to create a pointed triangle on the left div

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to ask how to create a pointed div to display the comments of the users. The pointed div should look like this :

[image]

Do you have any idea? thanks

It should appear like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/kNvTT) but just to put the triangle on the left side not on the top.

```
#pointed {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
padding: 4px;
color: white;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

#pointed:after,
#pointed::after {
position: absolute;
top: -5px;
left: 22px;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-bottom: solid 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
border-left: solid 5px transparent;
border-right: solid 5px transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a better picture of what you want to achieve? That is a whole page..

Comment: please show what at least you tried?

Comment: Actually they are not using images (well, the profile picture is an image of course, but it's not round), but they add a `border-radius: 100%;` to the image.

Comment: It should appear like this http://jsfiddle.net/kNvTT/ but just to put the triangle on the left side not on the top.

Comment: @user122935: What have you tried yourself? Have tried to understand what that fiddle is doing? Have you tried to make changes and see what happens?

Comment: @abhitalks : yes, I tried to change the left : -5px; top: 22px; to put it on the left but the triangle is still pointing on the top not on the left side.. :(

Comment: @user122935: Good. That's some improvement. Now try and figure out how is the triangle formed. Hint: See what borders are set.

Answer (score 8):

The triangle is generated by the border properties, so to make it point left you need to change the CSS to:

```
#pointed:after,
#pointed::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -5px;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: solid 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-bottom: solid 5px transparent;
    border-top: solid 5px transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LN6zG/

For more information on how the triangles are generated take a look here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant Code and Result . Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/kNvTT/9/)**.

```
#pointed {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
padding: 4px;
color: white;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

#pointed:after{
position: absolute;
left:-10px;
top: 18px;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-right: solid 10px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
border-top: solid 10px transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example will scale :)

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/kNvTT/13/)

[Example with scale - triangle centered](http://jsfiddle.net/kNvTT/14/)

```css
#pointed {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  min-height: 40px;
}

#pointed:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -5px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  border-right: solid 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-bottom: solid 5px transparent;
  border-top: solid 5px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="pointed">hello</div>
```